# Calendar disable dates with data from XSODATA binding SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, hana

I set up a HANA ddbb with an XSODATA service and i am able to use aggregation binding correctly to display data.

I have a table with users, departments and a date of visit.

I am trying to bind my calendar inside a `view.xml` ie `sap.ui.unified.Calendar`  and disable dates, retrieving data from HANA visit dates and disabling dates on the calendar that are stored in the database

for example ; I have table Visits with:  user1 department2 2018-08-13; 
                                         user2 department2 2018-09-21;

I would like to disable those specific dates and the corresponding week(the week part I will do later after I can figure out how to do the day)

Would it be possible to get that data,  using odata for disabling dates and manipulating it with the controller??

or is there another more simple way? For now im only  able to hard code it

```
        ((controller.js))
          disableDate:function(){
            var oModel2 = new JSONModel("DisableDate");
            oModel2.setData({
            minDate: new Date(2018, 0, 1), 
            maxDate: new Date(2050, 11, 31),
            disabled: [{start: new Date(2018, 0, 4), end: new Date(2018, 0, 18)},
                       {start: new Date(2016, 0, 15)}
                       ]
             //change this last part to variables  start and end dates and add info            

        });

this.getView().setModel(oModel2, "DisableDate") ;


                ((in xml.view)
                <u:Calendar
                id="calendar"
                select="handleCalendarSelect"
                minDate="{path: 'DisableDate>/minDate'}"
                maxDate="{path: 'DisableDate>/maxDate'}"
                disabledDates="{path: 'DisableDate>/disabled'}">
                <u:disabledDates>
                    <u:DateRange
                        startDate="{DisableDate>start}"
                        endDate="{DisableDate>end}"/>
                </u:disabledDates>
             </u:Calendar>
```

Thanks in advance, I have been trying to figure this one out for a couple of days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're going in the right direction by using bindings to connect your data (model) and the view. you create a (local) json view manually, though. Try to connect it to the model coming from backend (xsodata in your case)

1. you need to serve the data. For example Odata Entity `Visit`, each entry looks like this:

   Name: User1 (type Edm.String)
   Department: dep2 (type Edm.String)
   DateOfVisit: 2018-08-13 (type Edm.DateTime)
2. assume OData Model `VisitModel` is served by this odata Service
3. bind the view like this:

```xml
<u:Calendar
     ...
     disabledDates="{VisitModel>/VisitSet}">
     <u:disabledDates>
          <u:DateRange startDate="{VisitModel>DateOfVisit}" />
     </u:disabledDates>
</u:Calendar>
```

(if you have `StartDateOfVisit` and `EndDateOfVisit` on your entity, you may want to use `startDate` and `endDate` on DateRange object)

**UPDATE**: to disable full week, use

```xml
<u:Calendar
     ...
     disabledDates="{VisitModel>/VisitSet}">
     <u:disabledDates>
          <u:DateRange 
              startDate="{path: 'VisitModel>DateOfVisit', formatter: '.formatStartOfWeek'}" 
              endDate="{path: 'VisitModel>DateOfVisit', formatter: '.formatEndOfWeek'}" 
          />
     </u:disabledDates>
</u:Calendar>
```

and in your controller

```js
...
formatStartOfWeek: function(oDate) {
    if (oDate && oDate.getTime) {
        // compute Monday
        return new Date(oDate.getTime() - (oDate.getDay()-1)*24*60*60*1000 );
    } else {
        return oDate;
    }
},
formatEndOfWeek: function(oDate) {
    // compute and return Sunday
},
...
```

Comment: Great!! indeed it worked thanks for the help. now i just have to figure out how to disable that week of the selected date ;)

Comment: Just saw your update, im very gratefull for your time helping me, hopefully i can return the favor to the comunity soon ;)